# Valgrind errors due to freed memory?

Tags: c, valgrind

I am getting these Valgrind errors but really don't know what I did wrong. I'm assuming I am using pointers that point at a free memory location. Any help?

[image]

```
Node* insertNode(Node *root, int value){

    if(!root) {
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        root->data = value;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(value > root->data && root->right) {
        insertNode(root->right, value);
    }
    else if(value > root->data && !root->right) {
        root->right = insertNode(root->right, value);
    }
    else if(root->left) {
        insertNode(root->left, value);
    }
    else {
        root->left = insertNode(root->left, value);
    }

    return root;

}

Node* deleteNode(Node *root, int value) {

    if (root == NULL) 
        return root; 

    else if (value < root->data) {
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, value); 
    }

    else if (value > root->data) {
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, value); 
    }

    else if (root->left == NULL) { 
        Node *temp;
        temp = root->right; 
        free(root); 
        return temp; 
    } 

    else if (root->right == NULL) { 
        Node *temp;
        temp = root->left; 
        free(root); 
        return temp; 
        }  

    else {
        Node *temp;
        temp = smallestNode(root->right); 
        root->data = temp->data; 
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->data); 
    } 

    return root; 

}

Node* freeSubtree(Node *N) { if(!N) return;

    freeSubtree(N->left);
    free(N);
    freeSubtree(N->right);

}
```

Comment: `freeSubtree(N->right);` after freeing `N` is one problem.

Comment: Additionally, please don't post pictures of text, post the text itself (indented by 4-spaces so it formats as monospace font). In your image you have no more than `1KB` of text, yet your image requires `337.51 KB (345,615 bytes)` to store (it adds up....)

Comment: Also, if you're `valgrind`-ing, compile your code with debug symbols; then you get line numbers, not just function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to catch some of these things on your own is to make it a point to always null out any pointer you have freed so it won't ever have a lingering reference.

```
Node* freeSubtree(Node *N) { if(!N) return;

  freeSubtree(N->left);

  free(N); N = NULL;          // NULL out the pointer!

  freeSubtree(N->right);
}
```

and of course @Johnny Mopp has pointed out the actual bug that requires you to move the `free()` to the end.

In practice for code like this, I get even more aggressive in C with any function that might free memory by passing the *address* of the pointer so the address itself can be nulled out *in the caller*.

```
Node *freeSubtree(Node **PN)
{
  if (!PN  ||  !*PN) return;

  freeSubtree( &( (*PN)->left) );   // frees and NULLs the ->left pointer
  freeSubtree( &( (*PN)->right) );  // frees and NULLs the ->right pointer

  free(*PN);
  *PN = NULL;  // NULL the *caller's* handle on the pointer
}
```

If you want to use this technique, you really have to go all-in because the address-of-pointer parameter typically gets pretty widespread, but it's a godsend to never ever have use-after-free bugs.

Edit: use-after-free bugs are not always just bugs, sometimes they are *security* bugs.

Note: in C++ you can use ref parameters to do this far more readably.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that advise. At least then there will be no subtle `"invalid read of size XX"` error, things will just stop dead in their tracks.